# Angular 2 - Pagination next is not triggering the function to load the data for the next page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 4 and I am stuck in writing the code for pagination.
I am using separate services named "paginationFirst()" and "paginationNext()"  to load the data for the first page and next page respectively in a table. So that on clicking the "First" tab , the data from the first service should be loaded in the table through "firstPage()" function and on clicking the "Next" tab, the data from the second service should be loaded in the table through "nextPage()" function.
The data for the first page is loading fine but it is not loading the data for the next page when the next tab is clicked.
Both the services are working fine and displaying the correct data. I do not want to use npm pagination.
Please help in this regard.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="align-right">VALUE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected">
              item.value
           </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="pagination" *ngIf="tableDiv">
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="active" (click)="firstPage()" >First</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" (click)="previousPage()">Prev</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" (click)="nextPage()">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" (click)="lastPage">Last</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
firstPage(){
     this.calendarService.paginationFirst().subscribe(data => 
     this.calendarTableSelected = data);
}

nextPage(){
     this.calendarService.paginationNext().subscribe(data => 
     this.calendarTableSelected = data);
}
```

Service.ts

```
public paginationNext(){
    return this.http.get(environment.serverUrl+ '/api/nextpage')
               .map((responsePage:Response) => responsePage.json())
               .catch((err) => {
                   console.log('Error while getting response from service: '+ err);
                   return Observable.throw(err)
                 })
}

public paginationFirst() {
    return  this.http.get(environment.serverUrl+'/api/firstpage')
                  .map((resService4:Response) => resService4.json())
                  .catch((err) => {
                      console.log('Error while getting response from service: '+ err);
                     return Observable.throw(err)
              })
}
```

[Please click here to see the screen from the developer tools displaying that the service is returning response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S52Ry.png)

[Screenshot for the network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKelH.png)

Comment: I'm little bit confused here, you said "Both the services are working fine and displaying the correct data". How do you know they are working fine if it is not loading data for `nextPage`? And if it is "displaying the correct data", what is the problem here?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner The services are written in Python and when they are run in the browser, they are hitting the desired response. But from Angular frontend, clicking on next tab is not displaying any data. Ideally, it should replace the data of the table  with the next page service.

Comment: Ok, now I understand it. So, when you click on `Next` button and trigger `nextPage` method, do you see your request going through network and returning your desired data (on developer tools)?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Yes. I have also attached the screenshot of my developer tools. Please check the url in my post at the last line which I have just added for the screenshot. The request is going through the network. But when I click next, it redirects to the homepage instead of loading the data

Comment: Can you also add the picture of "Network" tab with your request and its response as well? If it redirects to homepage, I would assume it has something to do with your server, not the angular app.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I have added the screenshot in the post :)

Comment: When you click on it, it shows the request payload and the response. Are those what you expect for?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner yes that is what i expect but this is not happening

Comment: What I meant was, check the data coming from request and make sure they are correct. There may be some mistake with your request payload like you don't update a parameter when `nextPage` is clicked so that the server responds you with the initial data which will cause the problem you are having

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner No the data coming from the request is correct. The only problem is that the table is not getting updated on clicking on next.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Is it because I am using the same variable "calendarTableSelected" for the two services

Comment: That should not be a problem and you should use the same variable, since you update the same view with different data. I want you to add a console.log to nextPage subscribe method and let's make sure the data is the one you want and `this.calendarTableSelected = data` is working correctly.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I added console.log to both the functions first page and nextPage. And I am getting the same response for both of them which is Data from next page[object Object],[object Object],[object

Comment: Maybe put a debugger instead of console.log an examine your data or you can use JSON.stringify

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner ok I will do that and get back

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner It works fine now. I used buttons in the html instead of plain anchor tags for the next to make it work. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Yeah I missed that. You have `href=#` in your anchors. If you delete those, you should be fine. I have overlooked those anchors and focused on component part. Anyway, happy that it worked out :)

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Yeah it was the root cause. I missed that .

Comment: You should write your own answer and accept it for the people that might see this post later.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Yes you're right. I should do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Below I am posting my answer.

```
                    <div>
                        <button class="active" (click)="firstPage()" >First</button>
                    </div>


                    <div>
                        <button (click)="previousPage()">Prev</button>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button (click)="nextPage()">Next</button>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button (click)="lastPage()">Last</button>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component, you set the value like this :

```
this.calendarTableSelected = data
```

But in your HTML, you iterate like this

```
*ngFor="let item of calendarTable"
```

Either you weren't aware of that, or you forgot some piece of code !

Comment: Ok then, could you please make a console log of your returned data, and show it to us ?

Comment: @Neha, the Bunyamin question is about where you say the actual page to get the next page

Comment: Wrong answer @Eliseo ! There's no Bunyamin here

Comment: @Eliseo Please check the url for the screenshot in my last line of the post which I have just added.The actual page just redirects to the homepage on clicking next.

Comment: @trichetriche I have attached the screenshot. Please check the last line of my post